# How to add email address option in tikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

I am trying to create a poster using tikzposter class. Is there a way to display author's email address just below the author's affiliation?

The tags `\title,\author, \institute` already exist in tikzposter but nothing like `\email`. You can customize the title according to the manual in the following way:

```
\settitle{ 
\centering 
\vbox{
\vspace*{2em}    
\centering
{\bfseries\sffamily\fontsize{80pt}{96pt}\selectfont\@title\par}
\vspace*{1em}{\huge\sffamily \@author \par} 
\vspace*{1em}{\Large\sffamily \@institute\par}
%\@titlegraphic \\
%[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] 
}}
```

So I guess all it takes is to define something like `\@email`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you provide some code example of what you have?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler just to replace \@title with the title, etc.  (Frankly, easier than explaining how to make this work with \@email.)

Comment: I liked the template of fancytikz better. It looks more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to add the e-mail as part of the `\institute`, seeing as you wanted it immediately below the affiliation.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} 
\title{Something or other}
\author{A Bloke}
\institute{Department of Complete Nonsense\\[0.5cm] \url{bloke@nonsense.edu}}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the most simple workaround, but the very correct way to do it.

Comment: Though there could be a tiny bit of extra vertical space between them.

Comment: @Johannes_B You could probably argue that defining an `\email` macro as hinted at in the question is a more 'proper' way of doing it, but this is certainly a lot less work.

Comment: @Johannes_B Better?

Comment: That would be work for the maintainer of the class. When it comes to titles, i prefer to do them by hand as long as it is possible.

Comment: Much better :-)

Comment: This wouldn't work if you have many authors sharing affiliation or mixes

Comment: @AlejandroSazo Ehm, how so?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am trying to follow the scheme Author 1, Author 2, Author 3, Author 1 has one affiliation in common with author 2, and author 2 has an extra affilliation. It is correct that the institute in that case holds two emails that might be different? Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: @AlejandroSazo The institute holds whatever text you put in it, if you have two emails, just write two emails.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I agree with that, but the email is linked in my case to each person, not the affiliation (the problem is aesthetic, not about what texts some command might hold)

Comment: @AlejandroSazo I guess I don't really understand what you want exactly. Are you asking how to indicate the link betaen author and email? (Use e.g. superscripted numbers to indicate which email belongs to which person?) Are you asking for a different layout altogether? (If so, what kind of layout?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Perhaps I should make a new question! I will invoke you then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79384/discussion-between-alejandro-sazo-and-torbjorn-t).